# Warning implementing list filtering in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code to filter a list from data to be shown in a listView:

```
child: FutureBuilder(
               future: fetchPacientes('todo'),
               builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 if (snapshot.hasData) {
                   var filteredList = snapshot.data;
                   print("a minusculas:" +
                       _controller.text.toLowerCase());
                   filteredList = filteredList
                       .where((element) => (element.nombre
                       .toLowerCase()
                       .contains(
                       _controller.text.toLowerCase()) ||
                       element.NHC.toLowerCase().contains(
                           _controller.text.toLowerCase()) ||
                       element.apellidos.toLowerCase().contains(
                           _controller.text.toLowerCase())))
                       .toList();
```

But I am getting an error at point:

```
.where(...
```

This is the error output:

```
The method 'where' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
```

I am trying to migrate an old app to Null Safety, but I am not able to solve this issue. The proposed solution is to add a null check at `filteredList!`  but the error is not removed when doing that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that the object on which the `.` is applied (in this case, the `filteredList`) can be `null`, so it would throw an exception if `filteredList` will be actually `null`.

So, to avoid the error, you have these options:

- Add a `!` after `filteredList`: in this case, you're assuring the compiler that `filteredList` will never ever be null, and the error will disappear. Note that this doesn't actually prevent it from being `null`: you're just reassuring the compiler about it, and `filteredList` could still be `null`. In that case, the app will throw a dedicated exception telling you that it found a 'null' object when you declared in the code that this should not have happened
- Check if `filteredList` is `null`: add a few lines of code testing if it is really `null`, and then handle the case, even something basic like returning a `Text('filteredList is empty')`. After this, you can safely write `filteredList!` because you are sure that it will never be `null`, since you actually tested id.
- Set a default value for `filteredList` in case it's null: Dart has this operator that assigns a value to an object if it is `null`: `filteredList ??= []`. Again, after using this, you can safely write `filteredList!` because it will never be null.

PS sorry, didn't notice the last sentence. Since adding `!` and a `null` check isn't working, I'd try setting a default value for `filteredList`. Or maybe checking for `null` on `snapshot.data`, and then set an explicit non-nullable type for `filteredList`, like `List<Object> filteredList`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try all your proposals

Comment: I just looked up how I usually check for `FutureBuilder` data, since I wasn't sure: I use `as` to set the type of the data returned, after checking for `null` cases. Like this: `var map = snapshot.data as Map<String, Animal>`.

Comment: I have solved the issue adding: List<dynamic>? filteredList = snapshot
                                  .data as List?;
                              filteredList ??= [];

Answer (score 0):

The error is because`snapshot.data` can be `null`. Try adding a `?` before your `.where` like so :

```dart
filteredList = filteredList?.where(...);
```

Comment: As you propose the error changes to Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.